# Sort Ember Object Array with Promises

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-controllers

I have a model 
model/person

```
{

  firstName: DS.attr( 'string'),
  lastName: DS.attr( 'string'),
  email: DS.attr( 'string' ),
}
```

and another model 
model/project

```
{

  name:            DS.attr( 'string' ),
  code:            DS.attr( 'string' ),
  startDate:       DS.attr( 'date' ),
  endDate:         DS.attr( 'date' ),
  users : DS.hasMany('person', {async: true}),

}
```

then i'm retrieving all the projects with as an array which contains ember objects. 
since the project -> users is async its a promise. and i want to sort that array using the first name of the person. when the data is arrived accordingly and re render the hbs that is using the list

i have a computed property called

```
renderProjects = computed ('model.projects.[]')
{
 // trying to sort in here but data is not avaiable so its not getting sorted
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simply to use `.@each`:

```
renderProjects: computed ('model.projects.@each.firstName', function() {
  return this.users.sortBy('firstName');
})
```

this will recompute the `renderProjects` CP whenever the list of projects change or any `firstName` on any of the projects changes and then automagically update your view.

One important notice: You *can not* do `.@each.foo.bar`.
This is what you did in your [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/310f41de6940c5bb6624abbf6b1fd2f5?openFiles=templates.videos.index.hbs%2C&route=%2Fvideos) with `model.@each.myUser.name`.

In your twiddle the easiest fix is to add a `computed.alias` to the `video` model:

```
username: computed.alias('myUser.name'),
```

Then you can do this:

```
sortedVideos: computed('model.@each.username', function() {
  return this.get('model').sortBy('username');
})
```

[Here is a fixed twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/310f41de6940c5bb6624abbf6b1fd2f5?openFiles=controllers.videos.index.js%2C&route=%2Fvideos).

Comment: Your solution was my first attempt, but it doesn't work. Please check out https://ember-twiddle.com/310f41de6940c5bb6624abbf6b1fd2f5?openFiles=templates.videos.index.hbs%2C&route=%2Fvideos Maybe you can fix it

Comment: I would be happy to find such a pleasant solution.

Comment: Thanks @Lux for the answer ! this also worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

I would implement an observer, which watches the project array. Inside of the observer I would resolve the users-relationship sort the project array subsequently.

Please check out following code snippet.

```
  modelObserver: observer('model.[]', function() {
    let userPromises = this.get('model').map(project => project.get('users'));
    RSVP.all(userPromises).then(function() {
      this.set('sortedProjects', this.get('model').sortBy('users.firstObject.name'));
    }.bind(this));
  })
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response ! happy to say that it worked. i was not clear how to use promise array on that. using this example it resolved. Thank you again :)

Comment: this is a *really bad* idea! you should *never* use observers to set ember state. Usually there are *very few* reasons to use observers over CPs.

Comment: @Thilina Dinith Fonseka. Please checkout Lux's answer. His solution is how it should be in ember, much better. Please unaccept this answer.

Comment: @asdf thank you. i accepted your answer cause it worked for me. i will try lux answer as well.